# What is this intelligent race in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

This came up as a question in a trivia quiz.

> "Enter the name of an intelligent race, which is housed in a human hand, can live many thousands of years and tell me what is her talent?"

Well that's a question. Personally I couldn't find the correct answer.

What Star Wars race does this question refer to?

Comment: Well i can't add anything more because that's the quiz question ^^. Thats whole question from quiz there isnt any more info.

Comment: The Croke, from the Lando Calrissian novels by L. Neil Smith.  Their talent is illusion and shapeshifting.

Comment: Meta discussion: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5159/why-is-this-question-71065-closed

Comment: @Hussar, do you already know the answer? I've never Heard something like that from Star Wars.

Comment: Only if it was a question of Star Trek..

Answer (score 14):

Per @GreentstoneWalker's comment, I believe this may be an allusion to [The Croke](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Croke), mentioned in various [Lando Calrissian](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lando_Calrissian_and_the_Mindharp_of_Sharu) novels by L.Neil Smith.

The question seems to have been paraphrased from their Wookieepedia articles which reads...

> The Croke were a species of **sentient**, multi-legged beings who were
>   extremely long lived; **one individual enjoyed a lifespan of more than
>   20,000 years**. In their natural form, the species resembled
>   bristly-legged snails that were **diminutive enough to be held in a
>   Human hand.** However, Croke were naturally **skilled in illusion casting**,
>   a Force ability that allowed them to appear in larger guises.

The answer to the question would therefore be "**The Croke / Force Illusion**".

Comment: Phew, bit beyond your average pub quiz...

Comment: @Wikis - I'm hoping we don't see many more of these...

Comment: I liked it. Plus, I'm curious to see whether *any* question can defeat you!

Comment: My knowledge of the Star Wars EU is quite limited. I'm surprised DVK didn't catch this one.

Comment: @Richard: Your spare time is apparently unlimited, as you always track down these hard-to-research question that most of us shrug our shoulders at.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Or just copy it from someone else's comment..

Comment: @izkata - I'm happy to admit that his comment gave me the answer. I even waited 10 hours before posting and credited him on the first line.

Comment: @Richard The question was only open for 2 of those hours, and not everyone is always around.  But my annoyance was more at the other two who didn't see the credit to the other user.

Comment: @izkata - If he posts an answer of his own (or objects to my having posted this) then I would probably delete this and reward him with a bounty.

Comment: @Izkata: I know Greenstone Walker answered this in a comment. But how could I pass up a chance to mock Richard? My ego requires me to believe that only by having no life whatsoever could anyone possibly answer more of these questions than me.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - The benefits of having a job with unlimited internet access and no definable targets.

Comment: @Richard - I was planning to answer when I requested that the question be re-opened. But you beat me to it due to timezone advantage

Comment: @Richard unlimited internet access... no definable targets... You work for the government don't you.

Comment: @anotherguest - Me work in edukayshun.

Comment: @Richard: Explains why I answered more questions when I was employed than now that I'm on furlough.

Comment: @Richard - "Professor of Star Was and Related Sci-Fi"